# How to concatenate two ranges into a Vec

Tags: rust

How can I make a `Vec` containing `[0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0]` using ranges?
I tried this:

```
let mut a = vec![0..len];
let  b = vec![len..=0];
a.extend(&b);
```

But it raises an error:

```
type mismatch resolving `<&Vec<RangeInclusive<usize>> as IntoIterator>::Item == std::ops::Range<usize>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct syntax that I know of to create a `Vec` directly from a range. A range is an first-class object and implements `Iterator`, so you can [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) a range into a `Vec`.

Ranges must also be from low to high. To get a reversed range create a regular forward range and call [`rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) to create an iterator that iterates in reverse.

```
let mut a = (0..len).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let b = (0..=len).rev();
a.extend(&b);
```

You'll notice that `collect` requires `::<>`, the so-called [turbofish operator](https://techblog.tonsser.com/posts/what-is-rusts-turbofish). That's because it's a generic method that can convert an iterator into any type that implements [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html). There are many collection types that implement `FromIterator`, so we must tell it we want a `Vec` in particular.

Declaring `a`'s type would have also worked:

```
let mut a: Vec<_> = (0..len).collect();
let b = (0..=len).rev();
a.extend(&b);
```

It's also possible to construct the vector in place by [chaining](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) the two iterators together and then collecting the result. This way `a` doesn't need to be `mut`.

```
let a = (0..len).chain((0..=len).rev())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```rust
fn main() {
    let len = 4;
    let mut a = (0..len).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let b = (0..=len).rev();
    a.extend(b);
    println!("{:?}", a); // should be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
}
```